# How to parse JSON object response with counter using rest-assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

Can someone please help in parsing the JSON object in below format? The counter is dynamic and can be less, can be more. I want to get formattedBasePrice for all instances and store it in an array. What's the easiest way?

Thanks!

```
{
    "sales":
    {
        "0":
        {
            "formattedBasePrice": "$9.99",
            "formattedSalePrice": "$4.99",
            "formattedPlusPrice": "$4.99"
        },
        "1":
        {
            "formattedBasePrice": "$29.99",
            "formattedSalePrice": "$18.89",
            "formattedPlusPrice": "$7.79"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: This JSON in not valid.

Comment: What languaje are you using? java?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, was able to solve my problem using org.json.JSONObject. Yes, I'm using java. Had to do something like this:

`JSONObject countobj = obj.getJSONObject("sales");

for(int j=0;j< (countobj.length()); j++) {
String price = obj.getJSONObject("sales").getJSONObject(Integer.toString(j)).getString("formattedBasePrice");
p.add(price);
  }`